# missing libproc.h headers in solaris 11.0

Tags: solaris, sunos, opensolaris

I am trying to compile [pfiles.c](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/ptools/pfiles/pfiles.c)
It includes

```
#include <libproc.h>
```

And libproc.h includes

```
#include /sys/secflags.h
```

Both are missing from the image.

```
root@solaris11:~# cat /etc/*release
                       Oracle Solaris 11 11/11 X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
                        Assembled 18 October 2011
root@solaris11:~# uname -a
SunOS solaris11 5.11 11.0 i86pc i386 i86pc
root@solaris11:~#
```

I tried to update packages: system/header, system/library, developer/debug/mdb

```
root@solaris11:~# pkg install system/header
No updates necessary for this image.
root@solaris11:~# pkg search libproc
root@solaris11:~# pkg search libproc*
INDEX      ACTION VALUE                                                   PACKAGE
basename   file   usr/lib/sparcv9/Pegasus/providers/libProcessProvider.so pkg:/system/management/cim/pegasus@2.9.1-0.175.0.0.0.0.0
basename   file   usr/lib/Pegasus/providers/libProcessProvider.so         pkg:/system/management/cim/pegasus@2.9.1-0.175.0.0.0.0.0
basename   file   usr/lib/amd64/Pegasus/providers/libProcessProvider.so   pkg:/system/management/cim/pegasus@2.9.1-0.175.0.0.0.0.0
basename   file   usr/lib/Pegasus/providers/libProcessProvider.so         pkg:/system/management/cim/pegasus@2.9.1-0.175.0.0.0.0.0
basename   file   usr/lib/sparcv9/libProcessorProviderModule.so           pkg:/system/management/cim/pegasus@2.9.1-0.175.0.0.0.0.0
basename   file   usr/lib/libProcessorProviderModule.so                   pkg:/system/management/cim/pegasus@2.9.1-0.175.0.0.0.0.0
basename   file   usr/lib/amd64/libProcessorProviderModule.so             pkg:/system/management/cim/pegasus@2.9.1-0.175.0.0.0.0.0
basename   file   usr/lib/libProcessorProviderModule.so                   pkg:/system/management/cim/pegasus@2.9.1-0.175.0.0.0.0.0
basename   file   usr/lib/mdb/proc/libproc.so                             pkg:/developer/debug/mdb@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   usr/lib/mdb/proc/amd64/libproc.so                       pkg:/developer/debug/mdb@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   usr/lib/mdb/proc/libproc.so                             pkg:/developer/debug/mdb@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   usr/lib/mdb/proc/amd64/libproc.so                       pkg:/developer/debug/mdb@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   usr/lib/mdb/proc/libproc.so                             pkg:/developer/debug/mdb@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   usr/lib/mdb/proc/sparcv9/libproc.so                     pkg:/developer/debug/mdb@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   usr/lib/mdb/proc/libproc.so                             pkg:/developer/debug/mdb@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
base    name   link   lib/sparcv9/libproc.so                                  pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   link   usr/lib/sparcv9/libproc.so                              pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   link   lib/libproc.so                                          pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   link   lib/amd64/libproc.so                                    pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   link   usr/lib/libproc.so                                      pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   link   usr/lib/amd64/libproc.so                                pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   lib/sparcv9/libproc.so.1                                pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   lib/libproc.so.1                                        pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   lib/amd64/libproc.so.1                                  pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   lib/libproc.so.1                                        pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   lib/amd64/libproc.so.1                                  pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   file   lib/libproc.so.1                                        pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   link   usr/lib/sparcv9/libproc.so.1                            pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   link   usr/lib/libproc.so.1                                    pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
basename   link   usr/lib/amd64/libproc.so.1                              pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.1
root@solaris11:~# pkg install system/library
No updates necessary for this image.
root@solaris11:~# pkg install developer/debug/mdb
No updates necessary for this image.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is a private header, not part of the distro:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6439